# NextJS: Unload a script when the website URL has a parameter ?unload-script

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using webdriver to test our website. An Intercom widget gets baked into the screenshot as webdriver scrolls down. I've tried hiding Intercom through CSS, but this fails with a javascript error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style').`

Intercom is loaded by Segment.

Segment is loaded by NextJS, using the following in `/pages/document.tsx`:

```
<script
    type="text/partytown" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `!function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on","addSourceMiddleware","addIntegrationMiddleware","setAnonymousId","addDestinationMiddleware"];analytics.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);t.unshift(e);analytics.push(t);return analytics}};for(var e=0;e<analytics.methods.length;e++){var key=analytics.methods[e];analytics[key]=analytics.factory(key)}analytics.load=function(key,e){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript";t.async=!0;t.src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/" + key + "/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n);analytics._loadOptions=e};analytics._writeKey="xxxxx";;analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.15.3";analytics.load("xxxx");analytics.page();}}();` }} />
```

Is there a way to tell NextJS to unload the Segment script if webdriver loads a website URL with a parameter, e.g. `www.example.com?no-segment`

**EDIT**: `/pages/_document.tsx` is now:

```
import { Partytown } from '@builder.io/partytown/react';
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheetDocument } from 'next-sanity/studio'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 
const router = useRouter();
const [isUnloadSegment, setIsUnloadSegment] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (router.query['no-segment'] !== undefined) {
    setIsUnloadSegment(true);
  }
}, [router.query]);

export default class Document extends ServerStyleSheetDocument { 
  render() {   
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <Partytown debug={false} forward={['dataLayer.push']} />
          <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Medium.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: 500;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),;font-weight: 600;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;font-display: swap;}`}} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          {!isUnloadSegment && (
          <script
              type="text/partytown" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `!function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on","addSourceMiddleware","addIntegrationMiddleware","setAnonymousId","addDestinationMiddleware"];analytics.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);t.unshift(e);analytics.push(t);return analytics}};for(var e=0;e<analytics.methods.length;e++){var key=analytics.methods[e];analytics[key]=analytics.factory(key)}analytics.load=function(key,e){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript";t.async=!0;t.src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/" + key + "/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n);analytics._loadOptions=e};analytics._writeKey="piQWMo5agM7Jcwm9g4sJA1rhBfZfeAB3";;analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.15.3";analytics.load("piQWMo5agM7Jcwm9g4sJA1rhBfZfeAB3");analytics.page();}}();` }} />
          )}
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

But the local website produces an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have one solution for that. Please try if it works for you!!

Firstly from the Router URL, you can query the  **"no-segment"** availability and store it in the state so that you can use it to add conditions like this :

```
const router = useRouter();
const [isUnloadSegment, setIsUnloadSegment] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (router.query['no-segment'] !== undefined) {
    setIsUnloadSegment(true);
  }
}, [router.query]);
```

After that you can add condition as you said your script is in `/pages/document.tsx` so it can be as :

```
{!isUnloadSegment && (
  <script
    type="text/partytown" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `!function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on","addSourceMiddleware","addIntegrationMiddleware","setAnonymousId","addDestinationMiddleware"];analytics.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);t.unshift(e);analytics.push(t);return analytics}};for(var e=0;e<analytics.methods.length;e++){var key=analytics.methods[e];analytics[key]=analytics.factory(key)}analytics.load=function(key,e){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript";t.async=!0;t.src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/" + key + "/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n);analytics._loadOptions=e};analytics._writeKey="xxxxx";;analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.15.3";analytics.load("xxxx");analytics.page();}}();` }} />
)}
```

**NEXT PART EDITED :**

Here how you will code in class component .

```
import { Partytown } from '@builder.io/partytown/react';
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheetDocument } from 'next-sanity/studio';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

class Document extends ServerStyleSheetDocument {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isUnloadSegment: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { query } = useRouter();
    if (query['no-segment'] !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ isUnloadSegment: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isUnloadSegment } = this.state;

    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <Partytown debug={false} forward={['dataLayer.push']} />
          <style
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Medium.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: 500;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),;font-weight: 600;font-style: normal;font-display: swap;}@font-face {font-family: 'Poppins';src: url('/fonts/Poppins-Italic.woff2') format('woff2');font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;font-display: swap;}`,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          {!isUnloadSegment && (
            <script
              type="text/partytown"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `!function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on","addSourceMiddleware","addIntegrationMiddleware","setAnonymousId","addDestinationMiddleware"];analytics.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);t.unshift(e);analytics.push(t);return analytics}};for(var e=0;e<analytics.methods.length;e++){var key=analytics.methods[e];analytics[key]=analytics.factory(key)}analytics.load=function(key,e){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript";t.async=!0;t.src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/" + key + "/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n);analytics._loadOptions=e};analytics._writeKey="piQWMo5agM7Jcwm9g4sJA1rhBfZfeAB3";;analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.15.3";analytics.load("piQWMo5agM7Jcwm9g4sJA1rhBfZfeAB3");analytics.page();}}();`,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default Document;
```

Hope this will work well in  your case.

Comment: Looks good Jagroop. I've made an edit to my question, I receive an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

Comment: Hi you are trying to use Hooks in Class Component which is not possible . If you want your code in Class componenet . Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I will need to keep the Class component, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Steve . I have added a code for your reference in class Component . If still issue occur please let me know. Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thank you Jagroup, I still see the `src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"` code in `localhost:3000/?no-segment`

Comment: In VSCode, the `props` in `super(props);` is underlined in curly red. I don't think props are being passed.

Comment: Hi @Steve, can you share the error by hovering on the curly red or by checking in terminal? Else If your project has GitHub repo. then please share it so that  I can help you in this problem.

Comment: Hi Jagroop, `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`.